# ElasticSearch returns different results for timestamp and datetime

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which has field with mapping like this:

```
"ts": {
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "type": "date"
},
```

I tried 2 almost identical queries and got different results.

**First:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "ts": {
                  "from": 1414799400000,
                  "to": 1414799999000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Gave:**

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1934514,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   }
```

---

**Second:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "ts": {
                  "from": "2014-10-31T23:00:00",
                  "to": "2014-10-31T23:59:59"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Gave:**

```
"hits": {
      "total": 11333856,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   }
```

Weren't they supposed to return the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp and datetime provided are not equivalent check using [epoch_converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

```
1414799400000 => Fri, 31 Oct 2014 23:50:00 GMT]
1414799999000 => Fri, 31 Oct 2014 23:59:59 GMT
```

Whereas the range query using datetime  is :
    2014-10-31T23:00:00
    2014-10-31T23:59:59

In  short the two ranges are not the same.

Comment: Damn I spent too much time on sense. Indeed that was the main issue. After I changed timestamps again results were a little different but by adding ` "include_lower": true,"include_upper": false ` to datetimes, I got identical results